# Как сделать модальное окно по щелчку на этом значке (ссылка внутри)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Вот собственно какой-то набросок: [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/pbquzjh7/)

```css
#popup__toggle {
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}

.img-circle {
  background-color: #29AEE3;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}

.circlephone {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 2px solid #29AEE3;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  bottom: -25px;
  right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-animation: circle-anim 2.4s infinite ease-in-out !important;
  -moz-animation: circle-anim 2.4s infinite ease-in-out !important;
  -ms-animation: circle-anim 2.4s infinite ease-in-out !important;
  -o-animation: circle-anim 2.4s infinite ease-in-out !important;
  animation: circle-anim 2.4s infinite ease-in-out !important;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.circle-fill {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: #29AEE3;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  -webkit-animation: circle-fill-anim 2.3s infinite ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: circle-fill-anim 2.3s infinite ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: circle-fill-anim 2.3s infinite ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: circle-fill-anim 2.3s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: circle-fill-anim 2.3s infinite ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.img-circle {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  bottom: 14px;
  right: 49px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  opacity: .7;
}

.img-circleblock {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  background-image: url(images/mini.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation-name: tossing;
  -webkit-animation-name: tossing;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.img-circle:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes tossing {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-8deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(8deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-8deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes tossing {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes circle-anim {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.5) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .1;
    -moz-opacity: .1;
    -webkit-opacity: .1;
    -o-opacity: .1;
  }
  30% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .5;
    -moz-opacity: .5;
    -webkit-opacity: .5;
    -o-opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .6;
    -moz-opacity: .6;
    -webkit-opacity: .6;
    -o-opacity: .1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes circle-anim {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.5) skew(1deg);
    -webkit-opacity: .1;
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7) skew(1deg);
    -webkit-opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg);
    -webkit-opacity: .1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes circle-anim {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) kscale(0.5) skew(1deg);
    -o-opacity: .1;
  }
  30% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7) skew(1deg);
    -o-opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg);
    -o-opacity: .1;
  }
}

@keyframes circle-anim {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.5) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .1;
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes circle-fill-anim {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .2;
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) -moz-scale(1) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .2;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .2;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes circle-fill-anim {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .2;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .2;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .2;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes circle-fill-anim {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .2;
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .2;
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .2;
  }
}

@keyframes circle-fill-anim {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .2;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .2;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7) skew(1deg);
    opacity: .2;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="popup__toggle" onclick="return false;">
  <div class="circlephone" style="transform-origin: center;"></div>
  <div class="circle-fill" style="transform-origin: center;"></div>
  <div class="img-circle" style="transform-origin: center;">
    <div class="img-circleblock" style="transform-origin: center;"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Как сделать по щелчку на него модальное окно bootstrap 4 с формой обратной связи? Как ни пытаюсь - не выходит привязать ни по `id` элемента ни через `button`. Может быть решение есть через javascript?
Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили, траблы с оформлением, как обычно(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил к вашему примеру https://jsfiddle.net/pn1kroqw/ код из документации bootstrap 4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo

```
<a href="#" id="popup__toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="return false;"><div class="circlephone" style="transform-origin: center;"></div><div class="circle-fill" style="transform-origin: center;"></div><div class="img-circle" style="transform-origin: center;"><div class="img-circleblock" style="transform-origin: center;"></div></div></a>
```

Можно вызывать модальное окно по кнопке путем указания дата атрибутов `data-toggle="modal"` и `data-target="#myModal"`, внутри последнего указываете id модального окна.

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало, но не сообразил про тоггл и таргет, пытался через айди и саму кнопку. Правда если уж совсем по колхозному, то кнопку модального окна можно поверх этого синего круга поставить :D